# Encoding Characters not working on a list?

Tags: python, list, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a list like:

```
print alist    
['G\xc3\xbcnther', 'Santher']
```

And want to change it to:

```
['Günther', 'Santher']
```

I tried a lot of stuff like:

```
alist=[s.encode("utf-8") for s in alist]
print alist
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In others the word Günther gets lost, or G\xc3\xbcnther stays the same. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works fine here, you are just assuming the wrong thing from the API.

Printing a  object other that a string, converts it to a string first. In that case, the list is converted to a string representing the Python expression that, when entered, would evaluate to an equal list. This is the most useful way to display a list: you see exactly what is in there, sometimes it's just escaped.

Compare:

```
>>> a = ['test\'test\"test', 0, '0']

>>> print a[0]
test'test"test

>>> print a
['test\'test"test', 0, '0']
```

The letter `ü` is encoded in UTF-8 as two bytes: `\xc3\xbc`. Therefore, if you print the string `'G\xc3\xbcnther'` in a UTF-8 terminal, you will see `Günther`. If you save it to a file and open that file in a decent text editor, it will display `Günther` (maybe you'll have to poke the encoding setting a bit). For all intents and purposes, this is the best way to store the word “Günther” in a bytestring.

If you want to print a list in a nice manner, it's up to you to format it yourself. For example, if it's a list of strings, like in your example, `join` would work nice:

```
>>> print '; '.join(['G\xc3\xbcnther', 'Santher'])
Günther; Santher
```

(By the way: you can't encode a bytestring, it's already encoded. You can, however, decode it.)

Answer (score 1):

your code displays a *representational form* to see that in *string form* use this:

```
print alist[0]
```

python saves unicode characters as same, no way to change this :)

Comment: So i cant change the list? Really?

Comment: this doesn't make any problem, the style belong to python.

Comment: Is there ANY possibility to make a "ü" out of this "\xc3\xbc" in that list? Some kind of workaround? Making a string out of that list?

Comment: i don't have any idea for this. be patient for another answers, but inasmuch as i know no way to change this.